# what's wrong with the following code ? Getting error : Add is not a func or pointer

Tags: c, function, matrix, multidimensional-array

Only Value of 1st row of matrix is passing through Add().I am getting erroneous results.for Eg : matrix 1 has elements 1,2,3,4 .However when i print these values in add() ,I am getting 1,2,0,0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[100][100], arr1[100][100];

    int m, n, x, y, z;

    printf("\n Enter order of matrix");
    scanf("%d %d ", &m, &n);

    //ENTRY OF MATRIX

    printf("\n Enter Values of Matrix 1");
    for (x = 0; x < m; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
            scanf("%d ", &arr[x][y]);
    }

    printf("\n Enter Value of Matrix two ");
    for (x = 0; x < m; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
            scanf("%d ", &arr1[x][y]);
    }

    add(m, n, arr, arr1);

    return 0;
}

void add(int m, int n, int a[m][n], int b[m][n])
{   
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < m; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++)
            printf("%d     ", a[x][y]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix you indentation and add a blamk line between functions.  ATM, it just looks like a jumbled mess.

Comment: Maybe if your code formatting wasn't a complete mess, I'd bother taking a look at it.

Comment: ...otherwise we'll make you use Python

Comment: kindly check the code now

Comment: You're lying to the compiler and it gets its own back by not doing what you wanted.  You're passing two arrays of size 100x100; you're telling the compiler that you're passing two smaller arrays.  This will lead to unhappiness; the data was read into one set of memory locations and you're trying to read a different set.  You should have the function declared before it is used C99 requires this).  You most definitely should use it accurately.  You have some serious rethinking to do.  You can use the 100x100 matrices, but then you'll have to tell the function a lot more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, functions must be declared before use and the type of the arguments must match between declaration and call.

In OP's code, a couple of 2D array declared as

```
int arr[100][100];
```

are passed to a function defined after `main()` as

```
void add(int m, int n, a[m][n], b[m][n]) { /* ... */ }
```

Generating two issues:

- `add()` is used in `main()`, but it's not declared before, it's defined only after.
- `arr` and `arr1` are 2D arrays of 100 x 100 `int`s, but function `add()` as written, accepts two Variable Length Arrays of size `m` x `n`.

OP have two ways to fix, either they change the interface of the function and declare it before `main()`, like this:

```
void add(int m, int n, a[][100], b[][100]);  // and define after main
```

Or change the declarations of `arr` and `arr1`:

```
// includes...

void add(int m, int n, a[m][n], b[m][n]);  

int main(void)
{
    int m, n;
    // ...
    // read n and m before using them to declare the two VLA
    int arr[m][n], arr1[m][n];

    // ...

    add(m, n, arr, arr1);

    // ...
}

void add(int m, int n, a[m][n], b[m][n])
{
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please fix your indentation, it makes your code really hard to read.

This error is because you can't use a function that has not been declared.

To fix that, either add a prototype after your includes :

```
void add(int m,int n,int a[m][n],int b[m][n]);
```

Or try to put your whole function before your main.

Comment: This is part, but not all, of the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed some problem in your code.I have added declaration before main().

```
void add(int m,int n,int a[m][n],int b[m][n]);
```

Also, I have removed the **whitespace** into `scanf` function.

```
int main()
{
        int arr[100][100],arr1[100][100];
        int m,n,x,y,z;

        printf("\n Enter order of matrix");
        scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);

        //ENTRY OF MATRIX

        printf("\n Enter Values of Matrix 1");
        for(x=0;x<m;x++)
        {
                for(y=0;y<n;y++)
                        scanf("%d",&arr[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n Enter Value of Matrix two ");
        for(x=0;x<m;x++)
        {
                for(y=0;y<n;y++)
                        scanf("%d",&arr1[x][y]);
        }
        add(m,n,arr,arr1);
        return 0;
}

void add(int m,int n,int a[m][n],int b[m][n])
{

 // Your operation

}
```

Comment: does scanf considers whitespace while taking integers?

Comment: Note that passing 100x100 matrices but saying that you're passing a 4x5 matrix, for example, will lead to problems.  There's more to do.